# html5 datetime-local values when not complete

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, date

In chrome - I don't know in other browser (and I don't care for this time, but answer are valid for any of them) - if you didn't set the whole date (e.g. missing the hour and minutes  --:--), the value of the input is empty...

how can I know what not-empty values was inserted? or chrome waits to set the value of the input until all the fields are all set?

I thinked a brutal method that I don't like: *set a default value (e.g. today or 1/1/1970), then chrome has to set the value of the input, then all the values are ok even if the user don't set the date manually.*

```
<input id="INPUT" type="datetime-local" name="ciccio">
```

The render is something like

```
**-**-**** --:--
```

where * are field for the day,month,year.

If you type this:

```
12-03-2013 --:--
```

and requesting the value of the INPUT by javascript

```
console.log($('#INPUT').val());
//the result is "" (nothing).
```

but something has been inserted

Comment: "The input"... what input? Can you provide some clearer information about what you're talking about. Maybe some sample code.

Comment: @Dancrumb : sorry, I know I'm not very clear. I updated my question now

Comment: I've run into this issue today and I'm trying to find a way to detect that this is the case so the user can be alerted. No luck so far. :/

Comment: Just kidding. Calling the 'validity' attribute does the trick.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  As a workaround, I create two separate fields, one for both date and time, and one with only date.

Comment: @Logan struggling with same issue, calling 'validity' or checkValidity() does not help me (Chrome)

Comment: value sanitization algorithm does not allow to read incomplete value see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615364/hot-to-get-incomplete-datetime-local-input-values