# input type="datetime-local" value not set when starting with empty value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetimepicker

I'm using `datetime-local` type input field to capture date/time from a user. I am fully aware that this is only supported by Chrome & Opera browser and for my application, that's completely fine.

What I am noticing is that if I start with an empty value for this input field, the changes are not reflected when I blur out of this field. However when I start with a non-empty value for this input field, the changes are reflected.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<strong>Blank Date/Time (Changes are not reflected)</strong>
<br />
<input id="myDate" type="datetime-local" value="" />
<br />
Date Time Value:
<br />
<div id="myDateValue"></div>
<hr />
<strong>Non-Empty Date/Time (Changes are reflected)</strong>
<br />
<input id="myDate2" type="datetime-local" value="2016-09-16T00:00:00" />
<br />
Date Time Value:
<br />
<div id="myDateValue2"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#myDate').on('blur', function(evt) {
    var dateTimeValue = document.getElementById('myDate').value;
    $('#myDateValue').text('value = ' + dateTimeValue);
  });
    $('#myDate2').on('blur', function(evt) {
    var dateTimeValue = document.getElementById('myDate2').value;
    $('#myDateValue2').text('value = ' + dateTimeValue);
  });
});
```

Here's the link for the same on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qyyory4r/

This is happening in both Chrome & Opera.

What I am curious to know:

- Is this a known bug with this control? I tried searching for this but couldn't find anything.
- I think this input control still doesn't support `onChange` event and hence I am using `onBlur` event. Is there another way to get the changed value when starting with empty value?

Comment: This is not an answer to you questions, so I add some comments as a comment. Hope they will be helpful.

I was struggling with the same problem and I think I understood why does it behave in that way.

In your example `myDate` value is an empty string and `myDate2` value is a valid full date with time set to 00:00. So in `myDate` the time is not defined, but in `myDate2` it's defined.

Comment: Now when user selects the date with datepicker in `myDate`, the date is set to - for example - `2017-05-01 --:--` (without time), so the value is invalid (because has no time component set) and is seen in the code as an empty string. Instead in `myDate2` the time component is already set to `00:00`, so when the user changes the date component, the value is valid (becase has both date and time properly set).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Much appreciated. Considering it is perfectly legal to have a `null` value for a date/time value, I still think something's amiss in this control.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hot to get incomplete datetime-local input values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615364/hot-to-get-incomplete-datetime-local-input-values)

Comment: @rluks...Thanks! The problem I am facing is that even if I specify a valid value (though not the complete one - say I only specify the date part and not the time part), I get empty string back. Will that be considered as invalid date per the link you shared?