# Get value of input type time

Tags: jquery, input, time

I have

```
<input type='time' name='in' id='in' />
```

Whenever I ask for it's value on **keyup** by using

```
console.log("time value='"+$(this).val()+"'");
```

it only returns **time value=''** when the input value is **not complete**

**sample complete 03:45 AM**

**sample in complete 03:45**

I wanted to get what's the current value of input even if it's not yet properly complete.

Comment: @PhilippSander the question is not same with what you are referring.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26615470/2316112

Comment: `input="time"` elements consider an incomplete value invalid, so return an empty string instead. There's nothing you can do about this behaviour. It's part of the HTML5 spec.