# Is there a way to programmatically determine if an input date field is incomplete?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js

I'm stuck with the following question: how can I determine if an input date field is incompletely submitted? For example, if I send `12/09/aaaa` as a value, the value actually sent is `null`, which is the same value I obtain if I send `gg/mm/aaaa`, i.e. the empty value. Is there a way to discriminate via JS between the two cases? (Actually, I'm using Vue.js but I think it's not so important.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr: No, not natively

## Problem

This happens because the native HTML date input must either be empty or have a valid date according to the spec:

> ###### 4.10.5.1.7 Date state (type=date)
>
> [...] User agents must not allow the user to set the [value](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-fe-value) to a non-empty string that is not a [valid date string](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-date-string). [...]
>
> The `value` attribute, if specified and not empty, must have a value that is a [valid date string](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-date-string).
>
> The [value sanitization algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#value-sanitization-algorithm) is as follows: If the [value](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-fe-value) of the element is not a [valid date string](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-date-string), then set it to the empty string instead.

– [reference](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#date-state-(type=date))

This means, when the input is partially filled, no matter what form or input event is triggered (`submit`, `change`, etc) the value of the input will be an empty string.

## Solution

### Checking the input's validity state

Input elements have a property named `validity` to describe the [validity state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) of the input value. **In theory**, you could check the `badInput` or `valid` properties on the input's validity state object; if `badInput: true` or `valid: false` is present while the value is an empty string, you could infer the input has been partially completed. **In practice**, however, Safari seems to return `badInput: false` and `valid: true` even with a partially filled date input. See the table below:

|  | initial (no input) | partial (e.g. 01/mm/yyyy) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chrome (tested on 116.0.5845.140) | ``` { value: "", validity: { badInput: false, valid: true } } ``` | ``` { value: "", validity: { badInput: true, valid: false } } ``` |
| Firefox (tested on 116.0.2) | ``` { value: "", validity: { badInput: false, valid: true } } ``` | ``` { value: "", validity: { badInput: true, valid: false } } ``` |
| Safari (tested on 16.6) | ``` { value: "", validity: { badInput: false, valid: true } } ``` | ``` { value: "", validity: { badInput: false, valid: true } } ``` |

This test can be run with the snippet below:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input");

function log({ type, target: { validity, value, }}) {
  console.log({ type, validity, value });
}

log({ type: "load", target: input });

input.addEventListener("blur", log);

input.addEventListener("change", log);
```

```html
<input id="input" type="date" />
```

### Building your own custom date input

As a result, I think it's recommended to build your own custom input (or use a library). This would give you full and consistent control on how partial inputs are returned and validated.

Comment: @hcpl: FYI your edit has been significantly changed as I've added details on the option of checking the input's validity state (and why it might not be a good idea). If you wish, you can go into the revision history and post your edit as a standalone answer.

Comment: no worries, valid info added 

Answer (score 1):

You could regex, in this case, to validate if the provided input is a valid date format.

You could use the following regex

```
/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/
```

mentioned in the answer [regular expression to validate datetime format (MM/DD/YYYY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196451/regular-expression-to-validate-datetime-format-mm-dd-yyyy)

You could use (str).match(regex) in JS to use this feature.

I have shared an approach to use, regex can be updated based on use cases.

Comment: This only shows how to validate a date value, the issue here is that the value is set to an empty string `''` whenever the date entered is invalid because of HTML specifications (see accepted answers for details).

Answer (score 1):

let date = new Date('12/09/aaaa');

date == 'Invalid Date' //This will return true in date is not valid

Answer (score 0):

While it wont tell you explicitly the date field is 'incomplete', a useful property for a requirement like this is input.validity

[Hot to get incomplete datetime-local input values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615364/hot-to-get-incomplete-datetime-local-input-values)

> there is one helpfull property you can use input.validity that will provide you with badInput customError patternMismatch rangeOverflow rangeUnderflow stepMismatch tooLong typeMismatch valid

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState

Comment: This is likely to be user-agent specific, though. Safari (15.6, haven't tested with a newer version) will happily give you `valid: true` on the ValidityState for a partially-filled date.